# DESHABILITAR BOTON REACT-REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Estoy trabajando con una pequeña aplicacion en react-redux en donde uso 2 botones: AgregarCompra, Reservar. Lo que busco es que al momento de usar el boton "Reservar" este se deshabilite y no se pueda volver a usar para reservar el mismo producto.

El codigo en el componente UI que uso para el colocar ambos botones es:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const Productos = ({productos,agregarCompra,reservarCompra}) =>{

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div>
                {
                    productos.map(x=>(
                        <div key={x.id}>
                            <label>{x.nombre} Precio S/. {x.precio}</label>
                            <img src={x.imagen} alt="imagen del producto" width="250" height="200"/>
                            <button onClick={()=>agregarCompra(x)} className="btn btn-info">Agregar Compra</button>
                            <button onClick={()=>reservarCompra(x)} className="btn btn-success">Reservar</button>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
    productos:state.productos,
});

const mapStateToDispatch=(dispatch)=>({

    agregarCompra(producto){
        dispatch({
            type:'AGREGAR_COMPRA',producto
        })
    },
    reservarCompra(producto){
        dispatch({
            type:'RESERVAR_COMPRA',producto
        })
    }
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapStateToDispatch)(Productos);
```

el reducer es:

```
const reducerProducto=(state=initialState,action)=>{

    if(action.type==='AGREGAR_COMPRA'){
        return{
            ...state,
            comprados:state.comprados.concat(action.producto),
            productos:state.productos.filter((x)=>x.id!==action.producto.id),
        }
    }

    if(action.type==='DEVOLVER_COMPRA'){
        return{
            ...state,
            comprados:state.comprados.filter((x)=>x.id!==action.producto.id),
            productos:state.productos.concat(action.producto)
        }

    }

    if(action.type==='RESERVAR_COMPRA'){
        return{
            ...state,
            reservados:state.reservados.concat(action.producto),
            productos:state.productos.map((x)=>x),
        }
    }


    return state;
};
export default createStore(reducerProducto);
```

Tengo entendido que tengo que enviar un true o false desde el componente UI hacia el reducer para deshabilitar el boton de "Reservar" pero no se como hacerlo, podrian ayudarme?

Comment: Bueno de hecho necesitas más que eso, necesitas hacer un reducer donde tengas el id de los ítems seleccionados. Cuando cargues la página con el listado completo, ahí debes de evaluar si el producto está seleccionado o no, porque de nada sirve habilitar y deshabilitar un botón si no llevas el registro de los que fueron seleccionados. Ahí como dato te lo dejo